# Finding Smallest Prime Numbers that when divided equal Pi to 4 Decimal Places? Java

Tags: java, numbers, pi

I found an interesting question which I figured I could try to do; almost immediately I found a problem, which I cannot seem to fix.

When I run my code, there are no errors, yet it merely runs without returning anything. My loop seems to be OK, and I know my algorithm for finding prime numbers works, so I don't know what is wrong.

After editing a lot, I still have the same problem, yet when practically the same code is run in python, the python code runs and actually returns a result. Here is the changed code:

```
public class PrimeNumtoPi {

    static double pi = Math.PI;
    static double accuracy = 0.1;
    static int range = 10000;

    //checks whether an int is prime or not.
    static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            int i = 3;
            while (i < n / 2) {
                if(n % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                i += 2;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int nearestwhole(double n) {
        double remainder = n%1;
        if(remainder >= 0.5) {
            return (int) (n - remainder + 1);
        } else {
            return (int)(n - remainder);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isClose(double n) {
        if(abs(n - pi) < accuracy) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static double abs(double n) {
        if(n < 0) {
            return n * -1;
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int current = 3;
        while(current <= range) {
            int numerator = nearestwhole(current * pi);
            if (isPrime(numerator)) {
                if(isClose(numerator/current) == true) {
                    System.out.println(numerator + " and " + current);
                }
            }
            current += 2;
            while(isPrime(current) == false) {
                current += 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are dividing two ints which will result in an int again. Try `b/(double) j` instead.

Comment: You're also incrementing b and j at the same time - they are always equal.

Comment: and you increment b and j at the same time, so b/j will always be 1

Comment: When you test for equality, you should do it within a bound - like `Math.abs(pi - b / (double)j) < 0.0001`

Comment: `equal = false` is better than `notequal = true` and `isEqual = false` is even better

Comment: pi is better approximated as 3.1416 than as 3.1415, though this is immaterial to the question.

Comment: I simply wanted to use pi to 4 digits as that was the parameters of the question, however I am changing the code to allow for the user to input the accuracy level.

Answer (score 0):

**When talking about doubles, you cannot expect perfect accuracy**, doubles are *not* real (or rational) numbers.

Remember that there are infinite number of rational numbers in any (non trivial) range, but only finite number of bits to represent them.

Thus, **comparing for identity (==) of two doubles seldom returns the wanted result**.

For your purpose a valid alternative could be using java's [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, which lets you control the level of precision needed.

For more information you might want to read the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) on double precision and/or [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

---

In addition, it seems that `b` and `j` are increased always together, which is another issue in here. A brute force solution will have 2 nested loops each increasing one variable, rather then 1 loop increasing both.

And a comment about optimizing: You might want to use [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to improve efficiency of finding prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems in your code :

1. `b` and `j` are increamented at the same time so here `if (b / j == pi)`, `b/j` is always 1
2. your loop should start from 2 as 0,1 are not prime numbers : `for (int b = 2, j = 2; notequal == true`;....)`
3. `if ((isPrime(b)) && (isPrime(j)))` same number is checked for `primeness`
4. I checked running on my machine. It is running forever because of `b` and `j` are same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let j run from 2 to b (or b/something, for better performance).
2. As your PI is not perfect, so I think you expect some tolerance. The division of 2 prime numbers generally results in real numbers, which rarely equals to your PI. You can compare with PI +/- some tolerance to give a solution a better chance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compare every possible number and you don't need to compare ever digit.  You want to find a prime which when multiplied by PI is also a prime.

```
public static void findSmallInt() {
    double pi = 3.1415;
    for (int i = 3; ; i += 2) {
        if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
        int num = (int) Math.round(i * pi);
        if (!isPrime(num)) continue;
        if (round4((double) num / i) == pi) {
            System.out.println(num + "/" + i + "= "+(double) num/i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private static double round4(double v) {
    return Math.round(v * 1e4) / 1e4;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    findSmallInt();
}
```

prints

```
977/311= 3.1414790996784565
```

This may not be exactly what you want but you can see this is much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

The variables numerator and current are both ints, so dividing them will give you an int, of which the closest you can get to pi is 3, which has more than 0.1 difference, meaning isClose will never return true, so you will never print anything out.